# Delphi: Styled TMainMenu and TToolBar in TCoolBar

Tags: delphi, toolbar, vcl, menubar

I'm attempting to create an application menu and toolbar in Delphi XE3 that looks like the following (from a program I have):

[image: Main menu and toolbar in TCoolBar]

I'm able to replicate a portion of this look by doing the following:

1. Create a new VCL Forms application
2. Add a `TMainMenu` and insert template menus for File/Edit/etc.
3. Add a `TCoolBar` to the form
4. Add a `TToolBar` to the `TCoolBar`
5. Add a `TToolButton` to the `TToolBar` for each of File/Edit/etc. and choose the Group property
6. Delete the Menu property from the form (so no program menu shows)
7. Assign the MenuItem property for each `TToolButton` to the corresponding File/Edit/etc.
8. Add a second `TToolBar` to the `TCoolBar` beneath the first one

Here's what it looks like:

[image: My main menu and toolbar in TCoolBar]

It's somewhat similar but is still missing all the style elements to modify the look of the new application menu.

My question is, does anyone know of how to achieve a similar look, perhaps with a third-party component library?  It seems likely that the original developer used a third-party VCL library.  I'd like the drop shadow in addition to the styled menus and `TCoolBar`.

I've tried Raize Components, TMS Advanced Toolbars & Menus, and am in the process of trying DevExpress VCL components.  None of them seem to provide a solution, but perhaps I'm not familiar enough with them yet to figure it out.

Comment: Did you try to use a `TActionMainMenuBar`?

Comment: +1 @Sertac. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963441/tmainmenu-is-not-shown-when-the-vcl-styles-is-removed-from-the-nc-area) RRUZ also recommends to use `TActionMainMenuBar` instead of `TMainMenu`, and I would trust anything this guy says about VCL styles.

Comment: @kobik - Interesting usage in the question you linked... Indeed, styles might be owing him whatever grace it is receiving from developers (not sure if this is English, meant as a compliment :)).

Comment: Will XP never  die?  ;-)

Comment: @David - Not before metro dies, I hope...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Hmm. I'd love to stop supporting XP. Could throw away some gnarly old bits of code. Like dialog templates for extending file dialogs.

Comment: @David Not as long as a new Windows developer like myself comes along and notices that the XP styles look better than other/newer default styles.

Comment: @spurgeon No they don't. Well, neither of us is right. We just have different opinions. I trust you will let your users have the option of using platform default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi has come with an [`ActionBands`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/VCL.ActionBands_Sample) demo that can show you how to obtain this appearance "out of the box" for your menus using [`TActionMainMenuBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ActnMenus.TActionMainMenuBar) (and [`TActionToolBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ActnCtrls.TActionToolBar)). Just change the `Style` menu to `XP Style` in the demo:

[image: ActionBands demo]

The rest of your steps seem pretty well complete. For the images on the menu items and toolbar buttons, see the use of `ImageList` components in association with the `TActions` on the menu and toolbar in the demo.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed.  One issue though--my sample app doesn't show a drop shadow on the menu like yours does, even if I select "Menu Shadows" from the list after compiling and running.  The `TActionMainMenuBar` already has the Shadows property set by default too.

Comment: That *is* strange. I took the screen capture from a running instance of that app (Win7 64, run from the XE3 IDE, newly built). What OS are you running on?

Comment: Even more interesting, from the `Vcl.ActnMenus.TActionMainMenuBar.Shadows` docs: "The user can disable shadows through the OS, in which case the Shadows setting is ignored."  In my other Windows 7 virtual machine, it shows shadows.  So, somehow in my development virtual machine, I have shadows turned off.  As to where that property is stored by the OS, I have no idea.

Comment: [How to turn shadows on](http://techblog.ginktage.com/2011/07/how-to-enable-or-disable-shadows-in-windows-7/):  Right click My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Visual Effects -> "Show shadows under windows."  Interestingly, my "Show shadows under windows" option was already checked, but I unchecked and rechecked it again and hit OK.  Then the menu shadows showed up in the WordPad sample app.  Weird.

Comment: Ah, your search fu is better than mine. :-) Thanks for the update; I was looking for it as well. I started at the Desktop->Personalization, and waded through a bunch of stuff in Control Panel, but hadn't made it to My Computer yet.