# Delphi: onClick event of one MenuItem on the main form not firing

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

In my application I use `newMenu()` and `newSubMenu()` to create a `TMainMenu` on every form. I use the same code everywhere and the menu works as expected in every instance except for one single menu item on the main form. The first submenu is "Settings" where the first menu item is a submenu for changing the language of the application. Clicking on the second language in the menu works fine, but nothing happens when I click the first one. The `onclick` event does not fire even though it is assigned - it is just as if the menu item is disabled without looking like it. Since the menu works on the other forms I tried assigning the menu at a later stage (in `FormClick` instead of `FormShow`), but the issue is still there.

Why is that one particular menu item not working and why does it work on every form except the main form?

**Edit:** When trying to recreate the problem with a smaller application I found that the issue is caused by setting a custom style. Here is the code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, menus;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure langClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure otherClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    var Menu : TMainMenu;
        function createSettingsMenu: TMenuItem;
        function createLanguageMenu: TMenuItem;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
 uses vcl.themes, vcl.styles;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.langClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Label1.Caption := (Sender as TMenuItem).Caption;
end;

procedure TForm1.otherClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Label1.Caption := 'Other clicked';
end;

function TForm1.createSettingsMenu: TMenuItem;
 var
  alt: array[0..1] of TMenuItem;
begin
  alt[0] := createLanguageMenu;

  alt[1] := TMenuItem.Create(menu);
  alt[1].Caption := 'Other settings';
  alt[1].OnClick := otherClick;

  result := newSubMenu('Settings', 0, 'Settings', alt);
end;

function TForm1.createLanguageMenu: TMenuItem;
 var
  alt: array[0..1] of TMenuItem;
begin
  alt[0] := TMenuItem.Create(menu);
  alt[0].Caption := 'English';
  alt[0].OnClick := langClick;

  alt[1] := TMenuItem.Create(menu);
  alt[1].Caption := 'Swedish';
  alt[1].OnClick := langClick;

  result := newSubMenu('Language', 0, 'Language', alt);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TStyleManager.LoadFromFile('mystyle.vsf');
 TStyleManager.SetStyle('My Style');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
if not assigned(menu) then menu := newMenu(self, 'Meny',[createSettingsMenu]);
end;

end.
```

And the DFM:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 229
  ClientWidth = 187
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnShow = FormShow
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 80
    Top = 80
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label1'
  end
end
```

Why does setting a style cause the `onclick` event of the first menu item not to fire?

To clarify, I have checked that the `onClick` property of the first menu item ("English") is the assigned procedure `langClick`. It is just not firing.

Comment: Show a [minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
 With such example, we will be able to reproduce your problem, understand it and try to solve it.

Comment: If it's the "first" then I assume you use a loop that starts with `1` instead of `0`. Also it should be easy for you to debug if the `TMenuItem` of issue has a value of `nil` for its `onClick` property - just enumerate all recursively.

Comment: @fpiette I added an example and managed to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @AmigoJack Sorry if it was unclear from the original post - I have already checked that the value of `onClick` is what it is supposed to be. I have edited the post to add code and a clarification.

Comment: Please also add the DFM file as text in your question.

Comment: @fpiette added!

Comment: I can reproduce the error in Delphi XE7. Which version do you use?

Comment: @TomBrunberg I use Delphi 10.4

Comment: Confirmed to be an issue when standard VCL styles are used. No real solution yet, but a trick until the real fix: it is always the first item in the submenu that fails to respond. So, create a dummy item as the first one and set its `alt[0].Visible := False;` ~/~ You could also try to dive into [The Road to Delphi](https://theroadtodelphi.com/), Rodrigo (RRUZ  here at SO) has a tremendous knowledge and has built several utilities for the VCL styles

Comment: It is suggested in some posts here on SO (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963579/2292722) to use `TActionMainMenuBar` instead of the standard `TMainMenu` as that one has a better styling support.